# 75% of headaches due to poor bite?

Tags: medical-science, dentistry

I read the following claim on [a commercial dentistry](http://blog.durhamdentistry.com/should-you-have-ortho-treatment/) website:

> Some estimates suggest that 75% of all headaches are muscle-contraction headaches that could be tied to a poor bite. Wow!

What research is there to back this claim up?

Comment: 72.8 percent of all statistics are made up on the spot.

Comment: @Chris that's a lie. It's been statistically proven that the actual number is 93.8% +/- 1.4%